# Detecting start and stop of xhr request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a wysiwyg editor called summernote. This editor exists as an iframe within my application.

The editor accepts images and upon inserting an image into the editor, the image automatically starts to upload to my s3 bucked on aws. I've looked at the source code for django-summernote and I can't seem to see any references to ajax, so I'm not sure if it uses that or another technology.

What I do know is that during the upload process, an xhr request in initiated and remains active for the duration of the upload.

As soon as the user drops an image in the editor (and the xhr request starts), I'd like to show a spinner/loading icon so that they are aware that something is happening. I'd like the spinner to disappear once the xhr request has completed.

Is there a way that I can have javascript listen for any xhr requets and fire an event when one starts and when it ends?

[image]

Thanks!

Edit: Paul has indicated that I can use these:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log('UNSENT', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 0

xhr.open('GET', '/api', true);
console.log('OPENED', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 1

xhr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log('LOADING', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 3
};

xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('DONE', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 4
};

xhr.send(null);
```

Do I need to poll for the XMLHTTPRequest() every second and then check its status or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are [XHR readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) values. You could show the spinner at opened and then remove it at done.

Comment: This is great, Paul. Thank you! Now that I have this information, I've revised my question.

Comment: The `fetch` API is simpler to use though.

Comment: To the newer part of your question, you can use a function with [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) for changes to the `readyState`.